# Class should declare optional fields according to interface

Tags: typescript

I want to create a class that implements an interface and declares its fields as optionals but here the class is not required to do so.

```
class User {
  constructor(name: string, age: number) {}
}

interface Paginatable<TEntity> {
  page?: number;
  perPage?: number;
  filterField?: keyof TEntity;
  filterValue?: TEntity[keyof TEntity];
}

class PaginatedUser implements Paginatable<User> {
  // no fields declared but no error...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeBYAUNawD2AdhAC5ICuwxeSAFAWALYIBc0JSAlgQOYA00Ybi2gEyDAEbIAlGgC+WeZixdiyAGZhgCaAAVBXMMTDiQCADwAVAKIFiHYgE8AfGiw4ADoIQB+VqInIANxu0O7IekK+ImKSSMHY0GocIKpIAGIcCCAAJlEA1ggOeGrQ1rb2DvE4SSnIAGpgIGQ+rGV2jgDaBUUlbRUAuvGKWKCQMBEGqtnwyNAcDO6mTLbj+vRGJuYzSC4YCQD0+yJ4iZk5MPOLCMtT0OJkxMfQyEjUAHQfCkA)

At first glance the behavior TS displays here is not what some could expected but I understand (or at least I guess) why it happens: since the class `PaginatedUser` is of type `Paginatable` (whose fields are optional) the class is free to declare or not such fields. On the other hand, by implementing the `Paginatable` contract, it should be forced to declare those fields as optional.

Clearly my second assumption is not correct since the behavior is not what I observe. So:

1. Could someone provide more clarity on why it behaves as it does and not how I expected? What's the flaw on my assumptions?
2. How can I constrain a class to declare the fields but as optional?

[Edit]
**More context:** The example I provided above is to explain the conceptual problem. The real case I'm facing is that the `PaginatedUser` class is being used to annotate types for a GraphQL API (hence the need to declare optional fields on the class):

```
interface FilterableEntityInput<TOrderFields, TSearchFields> {
  page?: number;
  itemsPerPage?: number;
  orderBy?: OrderByFilter;
  filterValue?: string;
  orderByField?: TOrderFields;
  filterField?: TSearchFields;
}

@InputType()
export class FilterTagInput
  extends BaseFilterInput
  implements
    Partial<EntityFilterInput<TagEntity>>,
    FilterableEntityInput<TagEntityOrderableFields, TagEntitySearchableFields>
{
  @Field(() => TagEntityOrderableFields, { nullable: true })
  orderByField?: TagEntityOrderableFields;

  @Field(() => TagEntitySearchableFields, { nullable: true })
  filterField?: TagEntitySearchableFields;
}
```

I can provide even more context although I don't think it's necessary for the full comprehension of the issue.

Comment: Since those are optionals, "lack of them" fulfills optionality criteria right?

Comment: AD2) Dont use optionals. What would be the point of forcing to copy paste fields declarations anyway?

Comment: Please [edit] this to [ask a single primary question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/511366), or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." Is your main question "why is this allowed" or "how do I prevent it"?  If it's the latter, you should explain the use case in more detail; do you just want to require all the properties? Or actually require that they are *optional*? If it's the latter it's pretty complicated, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBYxkw) maybe.  How should we proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare your interface this way then your `class` should complain about the missing fields:

```js
interface Paginatable<TEntity> {
  page: number | undefined;
  perPage: number | undefined;
  filterField: keyof TEntity | undefined;
  filterValue: TEntity[keyof TEntity] | undefined;
}
```